# How to set up enterprise OIDs for Windows SNMP service?

Tags: windows, snmp, enterprise, mib, oid

I'm trying to use the SNMP service on Localhost, in Windows. I am not having a problem accessing the defined OID values of my device. I perform the operations with the [sharpsnmp](https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/) library.

For example, in the code below, I can change the sysContact data whose OID is "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4":

```
Messenger.Set(VersionCode.V2,
                       new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 161),
                       new OctetString("manager"), // read-write
                       new List<Variable> { new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.4.0"), new OctetString("test")) },
                       200);
```

But I can not integrated enterprise OID value to the system. If I run the following code, I get an error like this: "error in response. NotWritable. Index: 1. Errored Object ID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.37476.9000.128.1.1.0":

```
Messenger.Set(VersionCode.V2,
                           new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 161),
                           new OctetString("manager"),
                           new List<Variable> { new Variable(new ObjectIdentifier("1.3.6.1.4.1.37476.9000.128.1.1.0"), new OctetString("testHost")) },
                           200);
```

So what should I do? I could not find the necessary information on the internet. I would be very glad if you could help me.

Thanks.

Comment: If you were referring to the Windows SNMP service by saying "the SNMP service on Localhost", your only option is to write SNMP extension agent following Microsoft documentation to extend that service and add your own OIDs.

Comment: SNMP extension agent processes are pretty complicated. If I found sample dll files, maybe I would do something. However, it is still difficult. I guess I need to write C ++. I am surprised why no one has posted anything about this. I just found a program called AgenPro. However, it is sold for money. I don't know why Windows SNMP Service didn't add a process to automatically process MIB files in dll.

Comment: Microsoft preferred its own management API for Windows like WMI and PowerShell so Windows SNMP service hasn't been improved for decades.

Comment: Yes, so I'll have to write it myself. I hope I find a decent dll somewhere on the Internet. Thank you for your comment.